# How to alert using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$('.overdue').addClass('alert');
```

But this doesn't:

```
$('.overdue').alert('Your book is overdue.');
```

What is the correct jQuery syntax for:

```
FOR EACH CLASS="overdue"
   alert('Your book is overdue');
NEXT
```

Comment: define "alert". Do you want a popup box to come up (through `window.alert()`), or what?

Comment: Do you want the alert to show only when an element of class overdue is clicked upon?

Comment: I think alert is defined just right in the above example.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
$(".overdue").each( function() {
    alert("Your book is overdue.");
});
```

Note that ".addClass()" works because addClass is a function defined on the jQuery object. You can't just plop any old function on the end of a selector and expect it to work.

Also, probably a bad idea to bombard the user with n popups (where n = the number of books overdue).

Perhaps use the size function:

```
alert( "You have " + $(".overdue").size() + " books overdue." );
```

Comment: It's okay. Spend some time on the JQuery website reading their documentation. It'll make sense what's going on eventually.

Answer (score 11):

Don't do this, but this is how you would do it:

```
$(".overdue").each(function() { 
    alert("Your book is overdue"); 
});
```

The reason I say "don't do it" is because **nothing** is more annoying to users, in my opinion, than repeated pop-ups that cannot be stopped.  Instead, just use the `length` property and let them know that "You have X books overdue".

Comment: Annoying the user is what the client wants.

Answer (score 9):

For each works with JQuery as in

```
$(<selector>).each(function() {
   //this points to item
   alert('<msg>');
});
```

JQuery also, for a popup, has in the UI library a dialog widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Check it out, works really well.

HTH.

Comment: Good alternative to use jQuery-UI.